# How do I resume large file downloads, and obtain download progress using the ServiceStack client?

Tags: c#, servicestack, resume-download

I have a ServiceStack client that calls a service which returns an large data file of between 100MB to 10GB. Currently this client works perfectly over the LAN using the `Stream.CopyTo` method to save to file.

When the client is being run over a WAN (in addition to over a LAN) the ability to resume a download if it is stopped or loses a connection, as well as see the progress, has become important.

The service supports sending partial files but I am unclear on how to support this in the ServiceStack client or even if it is built in and I do not realise it.

Also the `CopyTo` method on the `stream` to copy to another `stream` does not report its progress so for a large file it can take hours and you can't tell its progress.  I have seen posts about a `CopyFrom` method that reports progress but I can't find that anywhere on the classes I am using.

My environment is the latest version of ServiceStack and latest version of Mono on Mac OS X and .NET 4.5 on Windows.

Being able to do concurrent downloads on a file for different segments would be ideal but just been able to resume downloads would be a huge help.

Can someone point out the best way to do this in the ServiceStack client? Most examples I found are just for the normal web client and are very old so wanted to see what the best way is with the later version of dotnet and mono as well as with ServiceStack.

If possible a basic example would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack supports [Partial Content Responses](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Service-return-types#partial-content-support) for services that return:

#### A Physical File

```
return new HttpResult(new FileInfo(filePath), request.MimeType);
```

#### A Memory Stream

```
return new HttpResult(ms, "audio/mpeg");
```

#### Raw Text

```
return new HttpResult(customText, "text/plain");
```

#### Static files served through ServiceStack

Partial Content is also available in static file downloads served directly through ServiceStack which lets you stream mp3 downloads or should you ever want to your static .html, .css, .js, etc.

### [Http Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils)

See [PartialContentResultTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/PartialContentResultTests.cs) for examples of how to request partial downloads using [ServiceStack's built-in HTTP Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils).

Comment: server side is all handled and working so it is just client side. If i understand correctly i should use the http utils GetBytesFromUrl method and the headers from the unit tests to get small chunks into memory and then write them out. If that is the case then i will work on wrapper class to do this that i will just reuse everywhere.